# unit testing vs automation selenium resume value

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, nunit, .net

I started working in automation development with selenium and am told it is a hot field and can earn some high-end coding salaries. We recently hired a new manager who once hired immediately took us off of that to do the dev's unit testing until it is 100% code coverage. I'm worried, among other issues with that strategy, that I will not return to automation I will be stuck. How much more value is automation vs unit testing career wise? Is this a regressive move professionally?

Comment: Hi disq, unfortunately career advice is off topic here. :-[

Answer (score 3):

Test automation is not high-end coding.  You will not become wealthy doing either test automation or unit testing.

Typically, unit-testing is not a separate job title.  Experience with unit testing is more likely to lead to a career as a developer than Selenium automation.  You are likely to make more money as a developer than as a tester.

Comment: yeah, somehow developers make more than testers. But if you are really good, test automation engineers are basically developers, their salary are comparable with developers on the same level.

Answer (score 1):

That was what I had previously believed also (because I've done dev) until my current position whereas the director is my source for this who actually sees the numbers.  Although, maybe its more specialialist thing.  You generally don't become wealthy as anyone's employee.

Comment: true, you will be a white collar, a middle class at most.

Comment: nothing wrong with that.